# Find common ID for records that match all criteria - how to build query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to make a SQL query and/or php code that only creates an array based on many criteria.  I have an array like this:

```
Array ( [1] => 1 [8] => 0 [2] => 1 )

The [1] refers to 'question_id' with the 1 being a 'value'
The [8] refers to 'question_id' with the 0 being a 'value'
The [2] refers to 'question_id' with the 1 being a 'value'
```

My database is set up like below and when I call it I am trying to get an array of ONLY the movie_ids that meet all of the above ^.  So say the array has [8] => 0.  The question_id should be 8 and the value corresponding to that record should be 0.  So say the array has [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjgvc.png) => 0.  The question_id should be 1 and the value corresponding to that record should be 0. If it meets the pair, and the other pairs before it, it should add that record to the array.

I've tried this, I'm using Codeigniter:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        $this->db->where('question_id', $key);
        $this->db->where('value', $value);
        $this->db->from('movies_values');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $res = $query->result();
        array_push($main_array,$res);
        }
```

$main_array is an empty array before it.
$array is an array like the one above.
But the problem wrong with this is, it checks one pair, so say [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjgvc.png) => 0 and if it matches, then it is added.  Rather than checking that it ALSO matches [8] => 0 and [2] => 1.

[image]

Comment: Please tag with the API used for that "fluid syntax". Also, include the schema - something seems wrong with the model if there is no JOIN going on. (It still might work with a GROUPing.)

Comment: Is this `CodeIgniter`, whatever it is,add name of the framework in tags.

Comment: Updated, with an image of the movies_values table! It's CodeIgniter

Comment: woo!! haha this is fun.

Comment: @DanielFein Unfortunately this is also not a very simple. There are two approaches I would of: 1) Join the table with itself, once for each check or, 2) COUNT(movie_id) over the number of matches and compare with the expected result of good matches.

Comment: What does joining the table with itself mean?

Comment: A "self join", e.g. - `FROM t a1 JOIN t a2 ON .. JOIN t a3 ON ..` although see Explosion's answer for a variation of #2 (note my comment about the GROUP BY/HAVING).

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the array to build a full `CASE` statement

```
$query = <<<SQL
    SELECT
        movie_id, question_id, value
    FROM
        t1
    WHERE
        CASE
SQL;
$params = array();
foreach ($array as $question_id => $value) {
    $query .= " WHEN question_id = ? THEN value = ? ";
    $params[] = $question_id;
    $params[] = $value;
}
$query .= " END";
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/741ff/2

Comment: Not to be completely dependent on you, but is this possible to be written in CodeIgniter?

Comment: @DanielFein probably .. at the very least you can use normal SQL in CI, right?

Comment: I am trying to look that up now, I'm trying to figure out, how do I implement this code? where do I make the SQL code?

Comment: @pst I'm confused by what you mean.  I was wrong on transcribing some of the values though.  It should be 1->1, 8->0, 2->1, which would select 1,1,1, 1,8,0, and 2,1,1 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/741ff/3

Comment: @ExplosionPills Ahh, I see how the case is being used. Anyway, run with `GROUP BY movie_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` for the correct[?] output. Should only be movie 2 selected, according to that fiddle data.

Comment: Where do you put GROUP BY movie_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 ?

Comment: @DanielFein At the very *end* - after the `END`! - of the sqlfiddle query posted.

Comment: The sqlfiddle query (the link) shows a different query than the one above.  The one above does not have an END.

Comment: @DanielFein Go with the fiddle - that's your test/target/proof.

Comment: But the fiddle has values that are unique to the fiddle.  I don't see how I could implement any of this into my code?

Comment: @DanielFein The SQL bit, not the sample data bit. I'm not sure how CodeIgniter allows queries like this, but now you know the process/general technique that will work.

Comment: It says either:    WHEN question_id = 1 THEN value = 1... or INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0).. Those numbers are unique to this fiddle, I don't understand?

Comment: @DanielFein (*Sigh*) .. the *target*. This answer contains the code to build the desired values (`$params[]` is to be used as placeholder values). If the code is missing a required `END`, add it yourself as deemed appropriate. As far as integrating into CodeIgniter code, search the CodeIgniter docks and/or search [stackoverflow] some.

Comment: Added `END` to avoid confusion.  I really don't know how CI works, but I'd be pretty surprised if it totally prevented you from running raw SQL queries.  You can always just skip the ORM layer and connect with PDO or the like directly after all.  Perhaps `where(' CASE ...', array($params))`

Comment: Ok, the reason I am asking many questions is because it is looking like this: "SELECT movie_id, question_id, value FROM t1 WHERE CASE WHEN question_id = ? THEN value = ? END"

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use the data from `$array` in a [where_in();](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) statement so you can avoid running SQL queries in a loop.

`$this->db->where_in('question_id', array_keys($array) );

$this->db->where_in('value', array_values($array) );`

which is equivalent to:
`SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE question_id IN (array_keys($array)) AND value IN (array_values($array));`

Comment: @DanielFein I do not know about active record, but plain SQL should keep them in pairs: `SELECT * FROM movies_values WHERE question_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND value IN (1,1,1);` will return only 2 results which is good, because question_id(2) has a value of 0, not 1 like in our query.